# GroupBy with multiple groups as a hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am using GroupBy create a hierarchical set of groups to use in multiple child grids.

Assume I have a query with with 6 columns, a, b, c, d, e, f.

Now, I need to group by a, then by b, then by c. and return the entire row in the group of c's.

```
var q = rows.GroupBy(x => x.a)
```

Ok, that's nice.  That gives me my group of a's.  Next, we look to group them by a and b.

```
var q1 = q.Select(g =>new {
    Key = g.Key,
    SubGroup = g.GroupBy(x => x.b)
}
```

Ok, that also works nice.  I get my group of a's with subgroups of b's.

Now I'm stumped at the third level.   I've tried various syntaxes, but most won't even compile.  The ones that do do not give the correct results.

```
var q2 = q1.Select(g1 => new {
    Key = g1.Key,
    SubGroup = g1.GroupBy(x => x.c)
}
```

This doesn't compile.  Tells me that there is no GroupBy on g1.

```
var q2 = q.Select(g1 => new {
    Key = g1.Key,
    SubGroup = g1.GroupBy(x => x.c)
}
```

This doesn't give me the b subgroup, only the a and c.

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

The Following also does not work, saying there is no definition for the g1.Key

```
var q2 = q.Select(g => new {
    Key = g.Key,
    SubGroup = g.Select(g1 => new {
            Key = g1.Key
            SubGroup = g1.GroupBy(a => a.c)
        })
```

I have such a poor grasp on what this is doing internally.

Comment: g is just a list of your entities and you are saying g.select which gives you the entity, but it doesn't have a key in it

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that.  I'm just not connecting the dots here and figuring out what the solution is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now, I'm not saying this is actually a good approach; it's probably going to be slow and the right way to do this, if performance matters, may be to sort the whole collection by these different criteria and then look at the different parts of the sorted collection.

But if you want to use `GroupBy` and `IGroupings` to manage it, you're working at it from the wrong end.  You want to start at the deepest level first and work up.

```
var groups = rows
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.A, x.B, x.C, x.D, x.E, x.F })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.A, x.Key.B, x.Key.C, x.Key.D, x.Key.E })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.A, x.Key.B, x.Key.C, x.Key.D, })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.A, x.Key.B, x.Key.C })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.A, x.Key.B })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key.A);

groups.First().Key;             // will be an A value
groups.First().First().First(); // will be an A, B, C group
```

Comment: This is very close to what i'm looking for, and really not that slow.  I can probably make this work, but it would be nice if I could make the subgroups only a single column, not multiples.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the multiple fields are necessary to get the lower groups to work. You da man!  Unless you're a woman, in which case you da woman!

Comment: As a bonus, If I convert my Linq-to-Sql query to a list prior to doing the grouping, then it significantly faster, because it does it in memory rather than with multiple queries on the sql server.  Adds a little load to the Web server, but I think it's a net win.

Answer (score 5):

GroupBy actually supports giving a list of elements to group by. Each group will contain the same first 3 items (A, B & C). You can get the key with the .Key method, and play around with the different rows with foreach. See Example:

```
    var groups = Elements.GroupBy(x => new {x.A, x.B, x.C});
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(group.Key + ": " + group.Count());
        foreach (var row in group)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(row.D);
        }
    }
```

Edit: Ahh, ok - what you need is this then:

```
    var groups = Elements
        .GroupBy(a => new {a.A})
        .Select(g1 => new {
            A = g1.Key, 
            Groups = g1
            .GroupBy(b=> new {b.B})
            .Select(g2 => new {
                B = g2.Key,
                Groups = g2
                .GroupBy(c => new {c.C})
                .Select(g3 => new {
                    C = g3.Key,
                    Rows = g3
                })
            })
        });

    foreach (var groupA in groups)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(groupA.A);
        foreach (var groupB in groupA.Groups)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("\t" + groupB.B);
            foreach (var groupC in groupB.Groups)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("\t\t" + groupC.C);
                foreach (var row in groupC.Rows)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Row: " + row.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, that creates one group, with a, b, and c.  Not collections of each.

Comment: Ok - I have changed it to nest the groups for you - better than the other answer since you don't need to do all the excessive nesting / multiple fields etc

Comment: Yes, that was actually kind of where I was trying to go originally, and I now see what I did wrong. However, mquander's response is really more of what I *meant* to do rather than what I was doing. The reason is that all the ojbects in the hiearchy are IGroupings rather than a mix of groupsings and IOrderedQueryables which is what your solution does.  But i'll +1 you