# Create IGrouping within IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, igrouping

I have a `List` of flat `ViewModels`.

```
var initialList = new List<ViewModel>
{
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "E", Id = 8},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "B outer", InnerCaption = "B inner", Caption = "A", Id = 5},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "B inner", Caption = "A", Id = 12},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "B outer", InnerCaption = "B inner", Caption = "B", Id = 9},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "B inner", Caption = "B", Id = 23},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "B outer", InnerCaption = "C inner", Caption = "A", Id = 10},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "B inner", Caption = "C", Id = 16},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "C", Id = 4},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "D", Id = 7},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "C outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "A", Id = 31},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "B outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "A", Id = 19},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "B outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "B", Id = 20},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "A", Id = 1},
    new ViewModel { OuterCaption = "A outer", InnerCaption = "A inner", Caption = "B", Id = 3}
}.OrderBy(vm => vm.OuterCaption).ThenBy(vm => vm.InnerCaption).ThenBy(vm => vm.Caption);
```

Where each `ViewModel` is as the following.

```
class ViewModel
{
    public string OuterCaption { get; set; }
    public string InnerCaption { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Now I want to group the `List` by the `OuterCaption` and later by the `InnerCaption`. I can group the `List` by the `OuterCaption` like this.

```
var list = initialList.GroupBy(vm => vm.OuterCaption).ToList();
```

And use it in my `View` like this and use `GroupBy` within my `View`.

```
foreach (var outerGrouping in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outerGrouping.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    foreach (var innerGrouping in outerGrouping.GroupBy(vm => vm.InnerCaption))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(innerGrouping.Key);

        foreach (var vm in innerGrouping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caption: " + vm.Caption + " Id:" + vm.Id);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
}
```

But I'd like to create a `IGrouping` within a `IGrouping` and not use `GroupBy` (or `Linq`) in my `View`. I do think that I should create something like `IReadOnlyList<IGrouping<string, IGrouping<string, ViewModel>>>` (might be wrong) for my `View`. How do I achieve this with my `initialList` so I can remove `Linq` from my `View`?

Here is the example code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hP2kxO

Comment: It's perfectly fine to perform grouping on flat data inside a view in order to present that data in the specific form the view is designed to represent. On contrary, the controller should probably not know about that specific form, and consequently not try to pre-group the data in a specific way that it knows the view will require, it would break the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy with multiple groups as a hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3435315/11683)

Comment: I'm going to use Linq within my view as you suggested. I posted the solution for my question down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working. It's not exactly what I'm looking for but it removes `Linq` from my `View`.

```
var list = initialList
    .GroupBy(vm => (vm.OuterCaption, ViewModel: vm))
    .GroupBy(group => group.Key.ViewModel.InnerCaption)
    .ToList();
```